# SpelEvaluationException When Using Spring Security Expressions with Query

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-data-rest

I'm trying to use Spring Security Expressions in Query. As shown in [36. Security Expressions within @Query](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.x/reference/htmlsingle/#data-query)

```
public interface BookRepository extends JpaRepository<Book, Long> {
    @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('AUTHOR')")
    @Query("select b from Book b where b.author.id = ?#{ principal?.id }")
    Page<Book> findAllOwned(Pageable p);
}
```

And I'm getting the error below.

```
2018-01-28 01:50:10.672 ERROR 12985 --- [nio-8443-exec-5] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E: Property or field 'aid' cannot be found on object of type 'java.lang.String' - maybe not public?] with root cause

org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: 
EL1008E: 
Property or field 'id' cannot be found on object of type 'java.lang.String' - maybe not public?
```

Please help to resolve the issue. What am I doing wrong?
I have included the classes I think necessary and relevant to this question below.

---

I have defined

```
@Bean
public SecurityEvaluationContextExtension securityEvaluationContextExtension() {
    return new SecurityEvaluationContextExtension();
}
```

And the user detail service

```
@Component
public class AppUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String s) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = userRepository.findByUsername(s);

        if (user == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException(String.format("The username %s doesn't exist", s));
        }

        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
        user.getRoles()
                .forEach(role -> {
                    authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getRoleName()));
                });

        return new PrincipalUser(user.getId(), user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(), authorities);

    }
}
```

Custom Principal User

```
public class PrincipalUser extends User {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = SpringSecurityCoreVersion.SERIAL_VERSION_UID;
    private Long id;

    public PrincipalUser(Long id, String username, String password, Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
        super(username, password, authorities);
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

Book Entity

```
@Entity
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
@Table(name = "book")
public class Book {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name", unique=true)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "shortcode")
    private String shortcode;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="author_user_id")
    private User author;

    @CreatedDate
    @Column(name = "created_date", columnDefinition="DATETIME")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date createdDate;

    @CreatedBy
    @Column(name="created_by")
    private String createdBy;

    @LastModifiedDate
    @Column(name = "last_modified_date", columnDefinition="DATETIME")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date lastModifiedDate;

    @LastModifiedBy
    @Column(name="last_modified_by")
    private String lastModifiedBy;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getShortcode() {
        return shortcode;
    }

    public void setShortcode(String shortcode) {
        this.shortcode = shortcode;
    }

    public User getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }

    public void setAuthor(User author) {
        this.author = author;
    }

    public Date getCreatedDate() {
        return createdDate;
    }

    public void setCreatedDate(Date createdDate) {
        this.createdDate = createdDate;
    }

    public String getCreatedBy() {
        return createdBy;
    }

    public void setCreatedBy(String createdBy) {
        this.createdBy = createdBy;
    }

    public Date getLastModifiedDate() {
        return lastModifiedDate;
    }

    public void setLastModifiedDate(Date lastModifiedDate) {
        this.lastModifiedDate = lastModifiedDate;
    }

    public String getLastModifiedBy() {
        return lastModifiedBy;
    }

    public void setLastModifiedBy(String lastModifiedBy) {
        this.lastModifiedBy = lastModifiedBy;
    }
}
```

User Entity

```
@Entity
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
@Table(name = "app_user")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "username", unique=true)
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "password")
    @JsonDeserialize(using = BCryptPasswordDeserializer.class )
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "is_active")
    private boolean isActive;

    @CreatedDate
    @Column(name = "created_date", columnDefinition="DATETIME")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date createdDate;

    @CreatedBy
    @Column(name="created_by")
    private String createdBy;

    @LastModifiedDate
    @Column(name = "last_modified_date", columnDefinition="DATETIME")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date lastModifiedDate;

    @LastModifiedBy
    @Column(name="last_modified_by")
    private String lastModifiedBy;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="author")   
    private List<Book> authoredBooks;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_role", joinColumns
            = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id",
            referencedColumnName = "id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id",
                    referencedColumnName = "id"))
    private List<Role> roles;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public boolean isActive() {
        return isActive;
    }

    public void setActive(boolean isActive) {
        this.isActive = isActive;
    }

    public Date getCreatedDate() {
        return createdDate;
    }

    public void setCreatedDate(Date createdDate) {
        this.createdDate = createdDate;
    }

    public String getCreatedBy() {
        return createdBy;
    }

    public void setCreatedBy(String createdBy) {
        this.createdBy = createdBy;
    }

    public Date getLastModifiedDate() {
        return lastModifiedDate;
    }

    public void setLastModifiedDate(Date lastModifiedDate) {
        this.lastModifiedDate = lastModifiedDate;
    }

    public String getLastModifiedBy() {
        return lastModifiedBy;
    }

    public void setLastModifiedBy(String lastModifiedBy) {
        this.lastModifiedBy = lastModifiedBy;
    }

    public List<Book> getAuthoredBooks() {
        return authoredBooks;
    }

    public void setAuthoredBooks(List<Book> authoredBooks) {
        this.authoredBooks = authoredBooks;
    }

    public List<Role> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }

    public void setRoles(List<Role> roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }
}
```

Extended SecurityEvaluationContextExtension

```
class SecurityEvaluationContextExtension extends EvaluationContextExtensionSupport {

  @Override
  public String getExtensionId() {
    return "security";
  }

  @Override
  public SecurityExpressionRoot getRootObject() {
    Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    return new SecurityExpressionRoot(authentication) {};
  }
}
```

Top few lines of the Stack trace:

```
ERROR 18238 --- [nio-8443-exec-9] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E: Property or field 'id' cannot be found on object of type 'java.lang.String' - maybe not public?] with root cause

org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E: Property or field 'id' cannot be found on object of type 'java.lang.String' - maybe not public?
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.readProperty(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:226) ~[spring-expression-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.getValueInternal(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:94) ~[spring-expression-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.access$000(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:46) ~[spring-expression-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference$AccessorLValue.getValue(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:379) ~[spring-expression-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueInternal(CompoundExpression.java:88) ~[spring-expression-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
```

[Full Stack Trace ...](https://gist.github.com/shamal/639615cfc4cc108dba7bb19f7c815a3a)

Comment: Book class has getters\setters?

Comment: May be just a typo ... in the book entity you have ...     private User auther;   authEr instead of authOr

Comment: @Black.Jack Yes. I did not paste them here to avoid lengthy code. Thanks for pointing out. @okaram it's not a typo. It's a foreign key to User table. `author` is a user type, that's why I'm checking if the logged in user (principal) id == book.author.id.

Comment: I think this is not enough to evaluate well. Paste 1:1 getters\setters and the User entity. Could you also tell as where exactly in your code Spring throws that error?

Comment: @Black.Jack Thanks a bunch for helping. I have added full stack trace, and also the full entity including getters/setters. There's no line in the stack trace where it points to lines of my code. But the error is from evaluating the SPEL. This is the only place in the project I have defined  `@Query`.

Comment: Put setter in PrincipalUser and please post User class implementation

Comment: Updated PrincipalUser, Posted User entity and included SecurityEvaluationContextExtension since I thought it would be relevant.

Answer (score 1):

There appears to be an extraneous ? in the example. Try:

```
@Query("select b from Book b where b.author.id = ?#{principal.id}")
```